# Drupal 8 - Programmatic Redirect In Form In Custom Block Module Not Working

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'm new to Drupal and have been asked to add a redirect in a custom module that was written for us. Unfortunately, the redirect is not working.

The module is implemented as a Block and is working without the redirect code. The module has a Form at the docroot\modules\custom\modulename\src\Form\filename.php location which is what I'm trying to edit.

This Form has a submitForm function in it in which I'm trying to use the following code:

```
$response = new RedirectResponse('/');
$response->send();
return;
```

This block has been placed on a page. Let's call it "/en/testpage". However, despite trying all sorts of valid pages in the RedirectResponse such as '/', '/en/members', etc., after the form is submitted, the user is always taken back to https://theNameOfTheWebsite/en/testpage#block-theNameOfTheBlock instead of what I'm trying to redirect to.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone would know how I could resolve this. I have been stuck on this problem for the last 2 days. Thanks. If it helps, the folder structure within the module's folder is similar to the following: "src\Form", "Plugin\Block", "template".

Comment: Your intentions are not quite clear. So the module outputs a form in a block and you want it to redirect after it the form is submitted? Is the form submitting via ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Hi [mkha13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11947141/mkha13) Welcome to Stackoverflow

> your code is not working with your redirection code

Check your log messages first if there is any logged message about this
at

> /admin/reports/dblog

Check if you are not including RedirectResponse class
 
If not included, include this with this line at top of your form class

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
```

Another solution is

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->setRedirect("routingName");
}
```

`routingName` is the machine name mentioned in the routing file.

Redirect to front page

```
$form_state->setRedirect('<front>');
```

Hope this helps you